# Can we perhaps be a little more serious with the LQP queue?

Tags: discussion, low-quality

I noticed today in the Low Quality Posts queue, there were at least 2 votes of "Looks OK" on [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/35578/755) to [the question about bug spray in airliners](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/35528/755). It's deleted now, but this was the text of the answer:

> The spray is part of a covert govt. operation to test zombie-apocalypse inducing viruses on unsuspecting patrons.

I know that a little more levity is usually allowed here than on some other SE sites and I personally like it that way, but that's pretty clearly not a useful answer to the question. I could understand it as a joke comment on the question, but it really doesn't seem like it belongs as an answer.

Comment: @mins Yes, it is. There are at least 2 "Looks OK" votes that I see for that answer on Feb 14 (when I posted this.) At any rate, that was just an example. This was more intended as just a reminder for people to pay a little more attention to what they're clicking "Looks OK" on in the review queue. Most things in the LQP queue are there for a reason.

Comment: Interestingly, one of the people who voted "looks OK" on another answer to that question (which now has a score of -6 and isn't deleted) also left a comment indicating why it wasn't actually an acceptable answer, so maybe they just clicked the wrong button in the queue?

Comment: Oh, I was looking on 13th. That could have been me, as I assume it was humor.

Comment: @mins The ones I saw weren't you. It listed the users, I just didn't bother mentioning it here, since my goal was just to bring attention to the issue and not to call out specific users.